# .Text not working in Selenium PhantomJS C#

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium, phantomjs

I want to get the text `Sample` from this structure:

```
<td id="IDName">Sample</td>
```

so I tried this:

```
driver1.FindElement(By.Id("IDName")).Text;
```

but it always return `null`.

Is there any reason why is it not working?

Comment: look if it under frame in the html dom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Hard to say why `.Text` is not working in your case, Might be possible when you are going to find element it's present on the `DOM` without text, So you should `WebDriverWait` to wait until element exists as below :-

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("IDName")));
element.Text;
```

Or might be possible it's designing issues of your HTML, then you can get text by using `.GetAttribute("innerHTML")` as below :-

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("IDName")));
element.GetAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Or then you can get text by using `.GetAttribute("textContent")` as below :-

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("IDName")));
element.GetAttribute("textContent");
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: hi! what is the namespace for WebDriverWait?

Comment: @AJB `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI`, have a look https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm.